# Eevee viewport and render looks blurry (won't display textures and lights as expected)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, blur

I´ve been having some troubles with eevee, the thing is that it looks blurry. It won't display my textures and lights as expected. It just looks like if it was "underwater". Besides, cycles render is way more different.
Evidence annex:
First image is eevee and the second one is cycles.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your Eevee window is showing it is still (or stuck?) rendering shaders.

Comment: Are you using an object with a volume shader ? They react differently in Eevee and Cycles and have different setting

Comment: Yes, my clouds have volume shader. Also, my eevee window is not stuck.